# Vue JS Error , The Requested Module does not provide an export named 'createApp'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, yarnpkg

I wrote hello world vue js 3 simple Programme. then it gives following error. I want to pass vue property value to HTML value. but it doesn't work . please help me to resolve this .

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myfirstproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hello world {{msg}}</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.browser'

        const app = createApp({
            data(){
                return {
                    msg: "Sri Lanka"
                }
            },
        }).mount('#app');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: _"vue js 3"_ and _`"vue": "^2.6.14"`_ do not align

Answer (score 0):

I edited `package.json` , and add  `"vue": "^3.2.26"` then delete node_modules and run `yarn install` ,

Then problem has been fixed